# SQL Server Paging query error - ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries and common table expressions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle

Here is a query I´m doing to return paged data to my web app to get the first 100 elements:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, Id,DateTime FROM Schema.MyDb WHERE 
Deleted='F' AND (Code>=2) AND (Type LIKE '%stock%') 
ORDER BY Datetime DESC) WHERE ROWNUM < 
100 AND RN > 0
```

This works pretty fine on Oracle database, but when running under SQL Server 2012  I´m getting the following error:

```
Message 1033, Level 15, State 1, Server NBOOK\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1:

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqu
eries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also speci
fied.
```

Any hint on how to fix this and make it work without loosing the logic (the final result  needs to be the 100 first rows of the ordered query) ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rownum` is specific to Oracle.  In SQL Server (and Oracle), you should use `row_number()` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() over (order by DateTime desc) as RN, Id, DateTime
      FROM Schema.MyDb
      WHERE Deleted = 'F' AND (Code >= 2) AND (Type LIKE '%stock%') 
     ) t
WHERE RN < 100 AND RN > 0;
```

In addition, the subquery needs an alias in SQL Server.  The above will work in both databases.

Comment: Will not OVER cause an overhead to the query, as it´s an analytical function ? This query will be called very often at my server...

Comment: @Mendez . . . Yes, sort of.  It shouldn't be much worse than the `order by`.  You could use `top` instead on SQL Server.  The version in the answer works in both databases.

Comment: Working fine in both SQLServer and Oracle. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Your order by is in a subquery.  Take it out and you should be good.